# 'TypeError: meme.find(...).forEach is not a function' in mongoose node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to loop through my collection in MongoDB so I tried `.forEach` to perform the action but it looks like this is not the right approach. Everytime I tried running it gives me error: `TypeError: meme.find(...).forEach is not  a function`

This is my code:

```
var meme = require('../app/model/meme');

meme.find().forEach(function(meme){
   meme.update({_id: meme._id}, {$set: { objectID: meme._id.toString().slice(10).slice(0,24)}}); 
});
```

I'm using mongoose and node.js to perform the action.

I'd appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You're using an async method `find` so you should use promises or callback to get the result , here some solutions choose what you want

// using promises

```
meme.find().then((memes) => {
  memes.forEach((meme) => {
    console.log(meme);
  });
});
```

// using callbacks

```
meme.find({}, (err, memes) => {
  memes.forEach((meme) => {
    console.log(meme);
  });
});
```

// using exec

```
meme.find().exec((err, memes) => {
  memes.forEach((meme) => {
    console.log(meme);
  });
});
```

Comment: When I run the code, it's not returning anything to my console?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
const f = async () => {
  for await (let m of meme.find()) {
    // do something with m
  }
}
```

mongoose "find" function returns query, which is iterable. So, no need to get all document at once.

Answer (score -1):

`find` method is async function so it doesn't return results but instead you need to pass a callback

[Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) you have documentation of that method

So you should make a call eg. like this:

```
meme.find().exec(function (err, docs) {
    // something
});
```

Comment: Can you demo how I should apply it to my code above?

Answer (score -1):

```
var meme = require('../app/model/meme');

meme.find().then(memes => {
    memes.forEach(function(meme){
        meme.update({_id: meme._id}, {$set: { objectID: meme._id.toString().slice(10).slice(0,24)}}); 
    });
})
```

try above one,
mongoose return a promise, you have to first execute the results after that you can iterate over that results.

Answer (score -1):

There are three main state in the `function()` You need to update the data if you find the data in [stream](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/querystream.html) then need to handle if something went wrong... and need to handle final that function has done it's work need to give `call back` no data found...

```
 var meme = require('../app/model/meme');

meme.find(query).stream()
  .on('data', function(meme){
   meme.update({_id: meme._id}, {$set: { objectID: meme._id.toString().slice(10).slice(0,24)}}); 
  })
  .on('error', function(err){
   //Getting `error` Something went wrong
  })
  .on('end', function(){
    // finally end
  });
```